# CPP - Using conditional variables - program crashes on wait if exit program

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Basically, I have two threads:

ONE: gets messages from the user, and adds them to the queue. - notifies the other thread that there's a message in the queue/

TWO: handles the messages and prints them out, waits for the other thread to notify them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

void getMessages();
void handleMessages();

using namespace std;

queue<int> msgQueue;
mutex mLock;
condition_variable con;


int main(void)
{
    thread msgHandle(handleMessages);
    getMessages();
    msgHandle.join();
}

// getting messages from user
void getMessages()
{
    int num = 0;
    do
    {
        // getting number from user
        cin >> num;
        // adding number to queue
        mLock.lock();
        msgQueue.push(num);
        mLock.unlock();
        // notifying
        con.notify_one();
    } while (num != -1);
}

// handles the message queue
void handleMessages()
{
    int curNum = 0;
    do
    {
        // waiting for reply
        unique_lock<mutex> uLock(mLock);
        try
        {
            con.wait(uLock);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            break;
        }
        // printing message from queue
        curNum = msgQueue.front();
        msgQueue.pop();
        cout << "Number: " << curNum << endl;
    } while (curNum != -1);
}
```

My question is how can I abort the wait part if I exit the application manually (X button)

Comment: the mutex should protect the queue both on pushing and on popping. you don't do it.

Comment: I do, left that part out cuz it's not related to the problem.

Comment: then post your **exact** code so we can help you.

Comment: If you knew exactly what's related to the problem, and what's not, you would not need to ask this question on stackoverflow.com. And if you do not know, then you need to edit your question and include a [mcve]. Without a [mcve] it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: The usual solution is to set a `quit` bool variable, and notify the conditional variable (in the X-button-clicked handler). And the thread, when wakes from `wait` checks the condition, what happened: a usual condition that a message arrived, or `quit` was set. Or neither (in case of spurious wakeup).

Comment: changed the code to the minimal complete verifiable example you mentioned. hope now its better